# About serverless batch processing in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am going to do batch processing with Google Cloud Platform.
Now we are making batch processing with Cloud Functions, but these have a time limit of 540 seconds.
Our batch process will take about 1 hour a day, once a day.

I also tried parallel processing on Cloud Functions, but because it does not work, I will not choose it.

We will do serverless batch processing and we plan to store the data in Firestore. Please tell me if you have a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem. in my case I went for:

1. Cloud Scheduler to start the job by pushing to Pub/Sub.
2. Pub/Sub triggers Cloud Functions.
3. Cloud Functions mounting a Compute Engine instance.
4. Compute Engine runs the batch workload and auto kills the instance once it’s done.

You can read by post on medium: https://link.medium.com/1K3NsElGYZ

It might help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to narrow down the scope of this question in order for the community to be able to provide an answer.

However, just to provide some guidelines to your issue, Cloud Functions are specially thought to work in a event-based environment, so if that is not your use case, you can maybe have a look at [other Severless approaches in the Platform](https://cloud.google.com/serverless/), maybe more specifically [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/). In App Engine, depending on the [type of scaling configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes) you choose, you can have requests running up to 24h. You can use [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/) for the storage part of App Engine.

If, on the other hand, your plan is to use Firebase with Firestore, feel free to edit your question adding the appropriate tags in order to bring some attention from other community users specialized in those topics. In any case, as I already mentioned, you would have to be more specific with your issue in order to have a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced to the same problematic. Here is my approach :

1. Using App Engine's cron task manager to starting the job
2. With App Engine, calling a Cloud Function with a simple http request
3. With Cloud Function, mounting a Compute Engine instance
4. With Compute Engine, processing the batch and auto kill the
   instance at the end of  job

Not sure if the right way.

Comment: I believe you describe perfectly what "App Engine" was designed for!

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud has recently launched [Batch](https://cloud.google.com/batch/) which is a job scheduler that can be used to run containerized or script based applications. If you're still looking for a platform, this should be able to meet your needs.

See the Google Cloud blog post announcing it at: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/new-batch-service-processes-batch-jobs-on-google-cloud

Answer (score 0):

You can use AI Platform Training to run any arbitrary Docker container — it doesn’t have to be a machine learning job. To have some arbitrary container executed on a GPU, you’d just do:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training gpu_function \
  --scale-tier BASIC_GPU \
  --region $REGION \
  --master-image-uri gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/some-image-name
```

This is just a REST API, so you have a variety of client libraries in a bunch of programming languages to invoke this from. There are no requirements for the container — just that it needs to have an entry point and that it is published in the container registry. It is possible to use custom machine types too.

For details, see:

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-containers-training

Answer (score 0):

I found myself looking for a solution to this problem and built something similar to what mesmacosta has described in a different answer, in the form of a reusable tool called [gcp-runbatch](https://github.com/bitcomplete/gcp-runbatch).

If you can package your workload into a Docker image then you can run it using gcp-runbatch. When triggered, it will do the following:

1. Create a new VM
2. On VM startup, `docker run` the specified image
3. When the `docker run` exits, the VM will be deleted

Some features that are supported:

- Invoke batch workload from the command line, or deploy as a Cloud Function and invoke that way (e.g. to trigger batch workloads via Cloud Scheduler)
- stdout and stderr will be piped to Cloud Logging
- Environment variables can be specified by the invoker, or pulled from Secret Manager

Here's an example command line invocation:

```
$ gcp-runbatch \
  --project-id=long-octane-350517 \
  --zone=us-central1-a \
  --service-account=1234567890-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
  hello-world
Successfully started instance runbatch-38408320. To tail batch logs run:
CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1 gcloud beta --project=long-octane-350517
logging tail 'logName="projects/long-octane-350517/logs/runbatch" AND
resource.labels.instance_id="runbatch-38408320"' --format='get(text_payload)'
```