# Is it possible to do micro-batching in serverless platforms like cloud run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run

I heavily use Google cloud run, for many reasons - one of the reasons is the simplicity of treating each request as stateless and handling it individually.

However I was thinking recently that for a service we have which simply writes data to a DB, it would be very handy to batch a few requests rather than write each one individually. Is this possible via serverless platforms - specifically cloud run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Cloud Run is stateless, you can't stack the requests (mean keep them, so statefull) and process them later on. You need an intermediary layer for that.

On good way, that I have already implemented, is to publish the request in PubSub (either directly, or you use a CLoud Run/Cloud Function to get the request and transform it in PubSub message).

Then, you can create a Cloud Scheduler, that trigger a Cloud Run service. This Cloud Run will pull the PubSub topic and read a bunch of messages (maybe all). And then, you have all the "request" in batch and you can process them "inside the Cloud Scheduler request" (don't forget that you can't process in background with Cloud Run, you must be in a request context. -> for now ;) )

Comment: Thanks @guillaume this is the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give a try to these blogs, I've done some reading and looks like you can pull some good ideas from them.
[Running a serverless batch workload on GCP with Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Functions, and Compute Engine](https://medium.com/google-cloud/running-a-serverless-batch-workload-on-gcp-with-cloud-scheduler-cloud-functions-and-compute-86c2bd573f25)

[Batching Jobs in GCP Using the Cloud Scheduler and Functions](https://towardsdatascience.com/batching-jobs-in-gcp-using-the-cloud-scheduler-and-functions-2d542410c11d)

Here is another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071934/about-serverless-batch-processing-in-gcp) thread that shows some similar approach.

Comment: Hi @Vicente this is not quite what I mean, I mean to receive more than one request (HTTP) create a mini batch and then process them on the instance.